# Horizontal barplot with offset in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

My dataset is like this, where the data points in each row or column are pandas objects.
[image]

Here is the dataset:
https://github.com/aebk2015/multipleboxplot.git

I want to have bar plots for each of the columns "Location" (P1 -P14) for each categories (92A11, 92B11, 82B11); something like this:
[image]

I have tried something like this and i can have a bar plots for each individual Pi (i=1...14) but not only is it a laborious, it does not look what I want:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(8,2))

sns.stripplot(data=df.loc[7]['92A11'].split(','), dodge=True, linewidth=1, ax=ax[0,0], color='black', jitter=False, orient='h')
sns.violinplot(data=df.loc[7]['92A11'].split(','),  ax=ax[0,0], color='orange', orient='h')

sns.stripplot(data=df.loc[7]['92B11'].split(','), dodge=True, linewidth=1, ax=ax[0,1], color='black', jitter=False, orient='h')
sns.violinplot(data=df.loc[7]['92B11'].split(','),  ax=ax[0,1], color='orange', orient='h')

sns.stripplot(data=df.loc[7]['82B11'].split(','), dodge=True, linewidth=1, ax=ax[0,2], color='black', jitter=False, orient='h')
sns.violinplot(data=df.loc[7]['82B11'].split(','),  ax=ax[0,2], color='orange', orient='h')

sns.stripplot(data=df.loc[6]['92A11'].split(','), dodge=True, linewidth=1, ax=ax[1,0], color='black', jitter=False, orient='h')
sns.violinplot(data=df.loc[6]['92A11'].split(','),  ax=ax[1,0], color='orange', orient='h')

sns.stripplot(data=df.loc[6]['92B11'].split(','), dodge=True, linewidth=1, ax=ax[1,1], color='black', jitter=False, orient='h')
sns.violinplot(data=df.loc[6]['92B11'].split(','),  ax=ax[1,1], color='orange', orient='h')

sns.stripplot(data=df.loc[6]['82B11'].split(','), dodge=True, linewidth=1, ax=ax[1,2], color='black', jitter=False, orient='h')
sns.violinplot(data=df.loc[6]['82B11'].split(','),  ax=ax[1,2], color='orange', orient='h')

ax[0,0].set_xlim(0,200)
ax[0,1].set_xlim(0,200)
ax[0,2].set_xlim(0,200)
ax[1,0].set_xlim(0,200)
ax[1,1].set_xlim(0,200)
ax[1,2].set_xlim(0,200)

ax[1,0].set_xlabel('92A11')
ax[1,1].set_xlabel('92A11')
ax[1,2].set_xlabel('92A11')

ax[0,0].set_ylabel('P8')
ax[1,0].set_ylabel('P7')
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot to explain how the values in the lists get converted to bars. E.g. is `10, 15` one long bar of `25`? Or something else?  Please provide test data in text form to makes things easily reproducible.  Preferably a short example, e.g. the first 3 rows and first 3 columns of your dataframe, together with their desired output.

Comment: @JohanC thanks for your comments. I added text data and plotted with violin plots so the distribution is more clear.

Comment: Now I'm very confused.  What is the relationship between the violin plot and the bars you want?

Comment: @JohanC there is no relationship between the two; i just plotted violin just the respond to your earlier comments as if there bar plot is only for one data point or more. For the purpose of what I want , either bar or violin plots are OK; my main problem is ho i can streamline the processing in one graph (and through subplots) without going through this laborious manual hard coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seaborn works easiest with its data in long form.  `pd.melt` can convert the 3 individual columns into a variable-name and value column.  `pd.explode` can convert lists in cells into multiple rows. As the current entries are strings, they can be converted to lists of numbers before calling `.explode()`.

The following code supposes you want box plots, not bars. It also supposes that an entry with only `'0'` is supposed to stay empty.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('raw_data.csv')
df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: 'Location'}) # suppose the first column is named 'Location'

df_melted = df.melt(id_vars='Location', var_name='Dataset', value_name='Datapoint')
df_melted['Datapoint'] = df_melted['Datapoint'].map(
    lambda s: [np.nan] if s == '0' else [float(v) for v in s.split(',')])
df_exploded = df_melted.explode(column='Datapoint', ignore_index=True)
df_exploded['Datapoint'] = pd.to_numeric(df_exploded['Datapoint']) # make sure the column is numeric

g = sns.catplot(data=df_exploded, col='Dataset', kind='box', x='Datapoint', y='Location')
g.set(xlabel='', ylabel='') # remove x and y label
```

[image: sns.catplot from wide dataframe]

PS: `df_merged` looks like:

```py
   Location Dataset                                          Datapoint
0        P1   92A11                                              [nan]
1        P2   92A11                                       [10.0, 15.0]
2        P3   92A11  [100.0, 40.0, 60.0, 50.0, 70.0, 50.0, 30.0, 40...
3        P4   92A11  [55.0, 40.0, 20.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 10....
4        P5   92A11                                              [nan]
...
```

`df_exploded` has each value inside the list into a separate row:

```py
   Location Dataset Datapoint
0        P1   92A11       NaN
1        P2   92A11      10.0
1        P2   92A11      15.0
2        P3   92A11     100.0
2        P3   92A11      40.0
...
```

Comment: thank you very much; this is exactly what I wanted. Now, I tried to add strip plot overlaid on box plot (similar to what I gave an example for violin plot) but it plots as a separate graph meaning one graph for box plot and one for strip plot. is it possible to have both in one graph?

Comment: You can use `g.map_dataframe(sns.stripplot, 'Datapoint', 'Location', orient='h', color='black')` to add a `stripplot` on top of the `catplot`.